# Compiling proj-4.9.3 on windows 7

Tags: c++, proj

I have some troubles in compiling proj-4.9.3 with mingw530_32 :

First like in this site : http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/mingw_how_to.html#libproj
I run :

```
./configure --without-mutex
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking C_WFLAGS for maximum warnings... -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /c/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/c/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking how to convert i686-pc-mingw32 file names to i686-pc-mingw32 format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking how to convert i686-pc-mingw32 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking for C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... func_cygming_dll_for_implib
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /c/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... no
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for localeconv... yes
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
checking whether to enable Java/JNI support... disabled
checking for mutexes... disabled by user
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cmake/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man1/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man3/Makefile
config.status: creating nad/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org/proj4/Makefile
config.status: creating nad/install
config.status: creating proj.pc
config.status: creating src/proj_config.h
config.status: src/proj_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

It's seems to be ok,
Then :

```
 $ make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/01_soft/proj-4.9.3/src'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/01_soft/proj-4.9.3/src'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DPROJ_LIB=\"/usr/local/share/proj\" -DMUTEX_stub   -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O2 -MT PJ_aeqd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/PJ_aeqd.Tpo -c -o PJ_aeqd.lo PJ_aeqd.c
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DPROJ_LIB=\"/usr/local/share/proj\" -DMUTEX_stub   -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O2 -MT PJ_aeqd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/PJ_aeqd.Tpo -c -o PJ_aeqd.lo PJ_aeqd.c'
Makefile:822: recipe for target 'PJ_aeqd.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [PJ_aeqd.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/01_soft/proj-4.9.3/src'
Makefile:464: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/01_soft/proj-4.9.3/src'
Makefile:439: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

That's weird because when i run manually this:

```
../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DPROJ_LIB=\"/usr/local/share/proj\" -DMUTEX_stub   -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O2 -MT PJ_aeqd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/PJ_aeqd.Tpo -c -o PJ_aeqd.lo PJ_aeqd.c
```

It's working. So I tried to change MakeFile to directly run this without the launcher (C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe) but without success.
I'm lost...
I reinstalled MINGW32 but same result. I googled this error without success. 
Could someone help me ?

Comment: consider installing git in a path without braces or remove the git bin path from your `PATH` environment variable while you're using mingw

Comment: Ok I removed git path and it's working ! Can you move your comment as Answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "Git for Windows" installation is clashing with your MinGW environment. So I would suggest to remove the PATH variable entry for the Git installation at least inside the MinGW environment.